# CodeIgniter Deployment

Tags: codeigniter

MySite in my PC is `http://localhost:8080/MySite/MyController`

when I deploy to hosting server, I can only access

`http://subdomain.MyDomain.com/MySite/MyController` but not `http://subdomain.MyDomain.com/MySite/MyController/AnyFunction` (it gave 404 error)

I have created `.htaccess` to remove index.php, it works fine in my PC;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I also set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Local setting:

```
  $config['base_url']='http://localhost:8080/MySite/';
  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Hosting setting:

```
  $config['base_url']='http://subdomain.MyDomain.com/MySite/';
  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Can anyone advice where have I gone wrong?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add a question mark to your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

source: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/181440/#862893